# decltype on BOOST_HANA_STRING

Tags: c++, decltype, boost-hana

My objective is to have a something like the following while writing the string "hello" as a regular string.

```
struct hello: element<hana::string<'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'>, std::int64_t>{};
```

I can have a function make a field of this type

```
template <typename ValueT, char... Cs>
element<boost::hana::string<Cs...>, ValueT> named_element(boost::hana::string<Cs...>&&, const ValueT& v = ValueT()){
    return element<boost::hana::string<Cs...>, ValueT>(v);
}
// ...
auto hello_e = named_element<int>(BOOST_HANA_STRING("hello"));
```

But my objective is not to have an object of type `element`. Instead subclass from it.

I need something like the following, that I can wrap inside a macro.Then I'll use the type `hello` as template parameter.

```
struct hello: decltype(named_element<int>(BOOST_HANA_STRING("name"))){};
```

The above won't compile. But something similar would help.

I am using C++14

Answer (score 2):

Because BOOST_HANA_STRING uses a lambda internally, it cannot be used in unevaluated context prior to C++20.  You will need to give a name to either the string or the field:

```
auto hello_e = named_element<int>(BOOST_HANA_STRING("hello"));
struct hello: decltype(hello_e){};
```

If this is not workable, and you cannot upggrade to C++20 but are comfortable depending on a Clang / gcc compiler extension, you can use `boost::hana::literals::operator""_s`:

```
#define BOOST_HANA_CONFIG_ENABLE_STRING_UDL 1 // at top of file
using namespace boost::hana::literals;
struct hello: decltype(named_element<int>("name"_s)){};
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking into this, and the problem seems to be that `BOOST_HANA_STRING` cannot be used for a c++14 `constexpr`. Luckily boost is quite amazing, so they've thought about that. Check the [HANA string doc](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/hana/doc/html/structboost_1_1hana_1_1string.html#a7f15faa77e126e1c2b08a2224ceefb84).

I've managed to make a compiling example

```cpp
#include <boost/hana.hpp>
namespace hana = boost::hana;

template <typename T, typename V>
class element{
private:
    V v;
public:
    constexpr element(V const& v) : v(v) {}
};

template <typename ValueT, char... Cs>
constexpr element<hana::string<Cs...>, ValueT> named_element(
    hana::string<Cs...>&&, const ValueT& v = ValueT()){
    return element<hana::string<Cs...>, ValueT>(v);
}

BOOST_HANA_CONSTEXPR_LAMBDA auto hello_e = named_element<int>(BOOST_HANA_STRING("hello"));

struct hello : decltype(hello_e) {
    hello() : decltype(hello_e)(0) {}
};

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    hello h;
}
```

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/o8foM6)

Comment: Lokking a bit more into this, `BOOST_HANA_CONSTEXPR_LAMBDA` actually doesn't do much... it expands to `constexpr` for C++>17 and to nothing for older versions. But the code seems to compile with gcc 6.1 and up